# Stuck with weird results when solving $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} + 4 \frac{dy}{dt} +4y = e^{-\alpha t}$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the general solution of the differential equation
>
> $$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} + 4 \frac{dy}{dt} +4y = e^{-\alpha t}$$
>
> where $α$ is a constant and $α ≠ 2$

Normally questions which ask to find the general solution are pretty straightforward, but this particular one has been causing me problems. I don't know how to do this right.

Here's what I did :

Auxillary Equation:

$$m^2+4m+4=0 \implies m=-2$$

Complementary function:

$$y=(C+Bt)e^{-2t}$$

---

Particular Integral:

$$y=Ae^{-\alpha t}$$

$$y'= -A \alpha e^{-\alpha t}$$

$$y'' = A (\alpha)^2 e^{-\alpha t}$$

Subsituiting to the equation:

$$A(\alpha)^2 - 4A \alpha + 4A = 1$$

Comparing coefficient GIVES $A=0$

Since this won't work, I restarted by **changing** the particular integral to :

Particular Integral:

$$y= e^{-\alpha t}$$

$$y'= -\alpha e^{-\alpha t}$$

$$y''= (\alpha)^2 e^{-\alpha t}$$

Putting to the equation I get:

$$(\alpha)^2 - 4\alpha + 4 =1$$

$$\alpha=1,3$$

I get two values of $\alpha$, atleast if one value was $2$. I could have rejected that and used the other one,

**I am stuck.** Please help.

Comment: You have too many A's you have an A in transient solution and you are using A in the steady state for an arbitrary constant.  One of those As should be a C or something else.

Comment: @dustin fixed it :)

Comment: You should be solving for the Constant A not alpha.  That is, A = 1/(a-2)^2 so y = Ae^{-at} where I used a for alpha and $a\neq 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that $\alpha$ is a constant, so we can solve for $A$ in terms of $\alpha$. Then:
\begin{align*}
A\alpha^2 - 4A\alpha + 4A &= 1 \\
A(\alpha^2 - 4\alpha + 4) &= 1 \\
A &= \frac{1}{(\alpha - 2)^2} &\text{since }\alpha \neq 2
\end{align*}
Hence, the general solution is:
$$
(C + Bt)e^{-2t} + \frac{1}{(\alpha - 2)^2}e^{-\alpha t}
$$

Comment: Do you have any idea as to why I got $\alpha= 1,3$ ? :)

Comment: @TheArtist because you solved $a^2 - 4a + 4 - 1 = 0$ where 1 was the coefficient of $e^{-at}$ when you should have been solving $A(a^2 - 4a + 4) = 1$ for A

Comment: By solving for $\alpha$ (even though it's a fixed arbitrary constant), you obtained a contradiction. So your guess that $y = e^{-\alpha x}$ is a particular solution was incorrect, and you need to guess a different particular solution.

Comment: Got it :DDDDDDD